# How can I create a header in a table for each new page with Word interop?

Tags: c#, interop, word-2007

I am trying to create a table with a header. I want this header to be repeated for each new page that the table takes. How can I do this in C# with Word 2007 Interop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table table;
/* ... */
table.Rows[1].HeadingFormat = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what word for me, Looping through each table at the end

```
            foreach (Table item in doc.Tables)
            {
                item.Rows[1].HeadingFormat = -1;
                item.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = true;
            }
```

and setting a style on each table with the property set to create a header on each new

```
                    t.set_Style(TableStyle);
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about `t.set_Style(TableStyle);` line? I tried many different styles but it still does not work for me. Mentioned `foreach` does not work without style. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This got worked for me: `var table = wordDocument.Tables.Add(tableRange, rowsNumber, columnsNumber, WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
table.Rows[1].HeadingFormat = -1;
table.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = true;` Sorry for such verbose example. Hope this will help to someone.

Comment: @RomanZinnatov "TableStyle" is the word style to apply to a table. It needs to be a registered table style in your word document.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!