# Create repeating rows in word using interop

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop

I have the below code

```
string html  = @"<table>
<tr>
<td>Column1</td>
<td>Column2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Column1 Data</td>
<td>Column 2 Data</td>
</tr></table>";
```

This is just a string which contains a html table(the one I actually have is pretty huge and I get it from  a stored proc)

The below code reads this html string and inserts it into a word document

```
public static bool CreateFormattedWord(string html)
    {
        Application wordApp = new Application();       
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add();      
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        ContentControl contentControl = doc.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, ref missing);     
        contentControl.Range.InsertFile(SaveToTemporaryFile(html), ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);       

        Console.Read();
        return true;
    }

    public static string SaveToTemporaryFile(string html)
    {
        string htmlTempFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), string.Format("{0}.html", System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()));
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(htmlTempFilePath))
        {
            html = string.Format("<html>{0}</html>", html);
            writer.WriteLine(html);
        }
        return htmlTempFilePath;
    }
```

I can go to the created word document select the table that I inserted and go to layouts and click on Repeat Table header and it repeats that in the document.

How can I achieve the same functionality using Interop within the code I have, so it has the Table headers repeated when the table is inserted into the document?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 var tableID = doc.Tables[1];
   tableID.Rows[1].HeadingFormat = -1;
```

The above code seems to do the trick

I got the answer from two links

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032867/accessing-a-table-by-name-in-word-using-c-sharp 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816957/how-can-i-create-a-header-in-a-table-for-each-new-page-with-word-interop
```

Comment: Hi user1221989, are you able to accept this answer, as @cubrr has suggested? Thanks. Ping me if you are not sure how to do so.

Comment: This does not work for me, the header never repeats on the rows

Comment: Downvoted, see above. Please try to respond to people who help you on this platform - content is best when it is curated as collaboratively as possible.